# How do I to change the style of a tag using Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a HTML tag which I want to only be visible when a condition is true, otherwise it will be hidden. To do this, I'm trying to change the `style` attribute using Razor, but still can't do this.

**Note that:** I don't want to use JQuery, I want to use only Razor.

How could I do this ?

Trying

```
<!--it will only visible if the conditional true-->
<div class="form-group" @(usuario.role == RoleType.Investidor) ? style="display:none;" : style="display:normal;">
    <h1>Description</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume something like this works:

```
<div class="form-group" style="@(usuario.role == RoleType.Investidor ? "display: none" : string.Empty)">
    <h1>Description</h1>
</div>
```

Move the ternary statement inside the attribute value for `style`. You may also be able to replace `string.Empty` with `null` - depending on context, that might enable the Razor engine to omit the attribute, rather than rendering an empty value.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to do something like that:

```
@if (usuario.role != RoleType.Investidor)
{
    <div class="form-group" style="display: normal">
        <h1>Description</h1>
    </div>
}
```

If `RoleType` equals `Investidor`, the div will not be shown at all.

If presence of this element is important to you, you can leave it like that:

```
@if (usuario.role != RoleType.Investidor)
{
    <div class="form-group" style="display: normal">
        <h1>Description</h1>
    </div>
} else {
    <div class="form-group" style="display: none">
        <h1>Description</h1>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Could also use the Bootstrap utility classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-show-hide instead of the style attribute.